# Simultaneous diagonalization on curved spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry

I have an operator $C$ that I wish to diagonalize on a Riemmanian manifold $M$ with *constant curvature* $\Lambda$
$$C = A + B$$
Now I know that these operators $A$ and $B$ commute in flat space, but on a curved space, they give
$$[A,B] = \Lambda B$$

Does this mean that $C$ is not diagonalizable on $M$, since $A$ and $B$ aren't simultaneously diagonalizible?

Comment: Great auto-correct error! I think you mean diagonalization in the title.

Comment: You are quite right, great autocorrect catch!